# Calculating requirements and dependencies extremly slow during Subversion SVN plugin installation on Eclipse Mars, why?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subversive, eclipse-mars

I am following this official guide to the **SVN Suversive plugin** installation on **Eclipse Mars**:  https://eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php

The problem is that it is taking a very absurde long time in the **calculating requirements ad dependencies** after that I select the specific component that have to be installed.

Why? How is it possible? Exist some alternative solution?

Answer (score 8):

This sometimes happens when one (or more) of your update sites are very slow.

Try again with "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" unchecked.

The disadvantage of "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" being unchecked is that if the software you are installing is missing dependencies, you will get an error about what that dependency is. To resolve the problem, either re-check the box, or manually select the update site that contains that dependency and install it.